# My Custom Excel UDF is not accessible (cell value = #NAME?)

Tags: excel, user-defined-functions, accessible

I have created a UDF Excel via ALT+F11 in own Module.
Have read many tutorials where everything seems so easy (that you can use your UDF in each Cell of opened Workbook). But I can't use my function.

Tried two test functions in Module (Test and Test2).

Checked everything (disabled all Macro security, allow access to VBA project model) but I don't see my custom function when I type "=" in a cell.

I'm using Excel in active Office 365 license so it is the newest version.

What could cause that my UDF is not applicable in the Excel cell?
I just get "#NAME?" / "#VALUE?" as result and no auto suggestion of function name...

maybe anyone has a hint for me what could cause that issue. Thx!

```
Public Function test()
    test = 1
End Function

Public Static Function test2()
    test2 = 123
End Function
```

Comment: Are you calling it through `=test()` on your worksheet? I assume you missing the `()` at the end.

Comment: Which module did you put the code into?

Comment: `Public Function Test()` ***`As What`***?

Comment: @Chronocidal If not declared, it is implicitly `as Variant`.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, I doubt it. Putting it in a wrong module would cause Excel to return a syntax error.

Comment: As suggested by @Rory, if you are not seeing your custom function, then you have not installed it into a regular module in your active workbook.  The `#NAME?` will follow.  If you were seeing the custom function, then you are probably not adding the `()` at the end in the worksheet

Comment: @JvdV Did you try it?  I just put it into a worksheet and reproduced what the OP reported.  In a regular module, but missing the `()`, still shows it in the dropdown prompt.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, Yes I tried. Putting function on sheet2, calling it on sheet1, resulting in syntax error. Therefore I suggested that `()` must be missing. I'm using Excel 2016, might this behaviour differ? Also, not showing in dropdown prompt.

Comment: @JvdV I cannot reproduce what you write.  If the function is in the worksheet module for sheet1, it shows a `#NAME?` no matter in what worksheet I enter the function, and whether I enter it as `=test` or `=test()`  I do not see a `Syntax Error`.  I doubt behavior has changed in different versions. I have O365 with all regular (not Insiders) updates.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, I'll write an answer to demonstrate. Hopefully that's allowed for this purpose.

Comment: As can be seen in @JvdV answer:  
 **alt-F11** opens the Visual Basic Editor.
Ensure your project is highlighted in the Project Explorer window.
Then, from the top menu, select **Insert/Module** and paste the code below the window that opens.

Comment: yes did all within the following file but don't get auto suggestion / UDF working in a cell... can you see any problem in this file ?! ufile.io/sswxp9em

Comment: my exact Office / Excel version is: ufile.io/sdxreosd

Answer (score 2):

@RonRosenfeld,

This is to demonstrate what behaviour I'm seeing:

- Scenario 1: Function pasted in `ThisWorkbook` calling it in Sheet1:

[image]

- Scenario 2: Function pasted in `Sheet2` calling it in Sheet1:

[image]

- Scenario 3: Function pasted in `Module1` calling it in Sheet1:

[image]

This is why I came to the conclusing the `()` must be missing to show the `#NAME` error since otherwise there would be a syntax error.

@OP, You seem to have put your function in a class module, instead of a regular module.

[image]

Comment: Maybe that behavior is due to your non-English version of Excel?  Can you upload the workbook and post a link?  I'd like to see if it occurs here.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Blame it on the foreigners! :)...... Just kidding. I'll upload it [here](https://ufile.io/ko1sdyyr)

Comment: Nope, do not see the syntax error.  If I move the (cut/paste) the functions from the regular module to the Workbook or Worksheet modules, I just get the `#NAME?` errors (with or without the `()`).  And, unless it is in a Regular Module, I don't see it in the drop-down.  Hence my thought that it is a placement problem (wrong type of module).  Interesting difference between the `American` and your version, though.

Comment: Thanks for your hints right now, but don't get it work so far... my exact version can you see in following screenshot: https://ufile.io/sdxreosd

Comment: @baer999, You have put it in a class module, instead of a regular module.

Comment: "You seem to have put your function in a class module, instead of a regular module.": 
along with the picture was enough to solve my case

Answer (score 0):

Functions located in a module created using: add a Module(second menu from left)/Module
succesfully shows up in the function menu.